# org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/ypd/a/entity/Employee.hbm.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I got a issue when I test the method:

> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
>   信息: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter, junit-vintage]
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> **org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/ypd/a/entity/Employee.hbm.xml not found**
>
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2314)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2280)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2260)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2213)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2128)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2107)
>       at com.ypd.a.entity.App.testHello(App.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:289)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(MethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:63)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:80)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:87)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:87)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:129)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:59)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

It state the **org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/ypd/a/entity/Employee.hbm.xml not found**

But in the project directory:

[image]

And in the `Employee.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">



<hibernate-mapping package="com.ypd.a.entity">
    <class name="Employee" table="t_employee">

        <id name="empId" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name="empName" column="emp_name"></property>
        <property name="workDate" column="workDate"></property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration files should put in the resources directory, the java directory only store `.java` file.